# Передача переменной

Tags: python, aiogram

```
def buy(now="",bow="", mess_name=""):
    if now == 0 and bow == 0:
        btnAdditionZip = InlineKeyboardButton('Докупить архив', callback_data='button5', mess_name = mess_name)
        btnAdditionPasss = InlineKeyboardButton('Докупить пароль', callback_data='button5', mess_name = mess_name)
        mainAddition = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnAdditionZip, btnAdditionPasss)
    
    if now == 1 and bow == 0:
        btnAdditionPass = InlineKeyboardButton('Докупить пароль', callback_data='button5', mess_name = mess_name)
        mainAddition = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnAdditionPass)
    return mainAddition
```

При нажатии на кнопку button5 я передаю переменную mess_name сюда:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button5')
async def process_callback_button5(mess_name,callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    if mess_name != None:
        mess_name = name_zip_pass
    else:
        pass
    there_money = db.user_money(callback_query.from_user.id)
    if (there_money < cost):
        message_money = cost - there_money
        comment = str(callback_query.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))

        bill = p2p.bill(amount = message_money, lifetime = 15, comment = comment)
        db.add_check(callback_query.from_user.id, message_money, bill.bill_id)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"Оплата услуги в {message_money} рублей\nСсылка на оплату: {bill.pay_url}\nКомментарий к оплате: {comment}", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))
    else:
        user_money = db.user_money(callback_query.from_user.id)
        db.set_money(callback_query.from_user.id, user_money-cost)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"Вы совершили покупку!")
        await bot.send_document(callback_query.from_user.id, open(f'zip/{name_zip_pass}.zip', 'rb'), reply_markup = nav.mainPassPay)
```

выдает ошибку :

```
process_callback_button5() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_query'
```

Comment: а если попробовать так: async def process_callback_button5(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, mess_name): ... поменять местами аргументы функции

Comment: @Anatoly Kritskiy process_callback_button5() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mess_name'

Comment: А в чем проблема передавать эту переменную в колбек дате, а потом доставать ее в хендлер из строки?

Comment: Да и вряд-ли можно в InlineKeyboardMarkup таки образом как делаете вы передавать данные. Исключительно callback_data

Comment: @oleksandrigo Можете показать как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Вместо этого
btnAdditionZip = InlineKeyboardButton('Докупить архив', callback_data='button5', mess_name = mess_name)
# Сделай так
btnAdditionZip = InlineKeyboardButton('Докупить архив', callback_data=f'button5:{mess_name}')

# А хендлер сделай на манер
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="button5")
async def process_callback_button5(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    mess_name = callback_query.data.split(":")[1]
```